# Partial Upgrade to 20.04 hangs

Tags: grub2, upgrade

Help, please. Yesterday, Jan. 31 2021, I was prompted to run a partial upgrade on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. I proceeded and the upgrade hung over 15 hours ago building grub-common, just after "found initrd-image.-5.4..0-64-generic"

[*I am unable to use the desktop as DNS is not working and networking restart does not help.*] This is now fixed, but the partial upgrade is still hung.

**I assume I should not abort the upgrade without severe consequences - correct?**

Suggestions would be welcome. My computer is sluggish when unlocking the screen, will not suspend and gparted and disc  utility will not run.

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently it was in an interruptible state. When I disconnected one of the external backup discs, after a hunch that it was holding up the grub build, the system hung solidly. I rebooted and all appears to be well. I don't know how to proceed if offered a partial upgrade again. I am running disc diagnostics now.

Ran software-updater and chose "Continue" instead of partial upgrade. It said the software index was broken and to run apt-get install -f. After doing that and running software-updater the updates ran normally and it then said my computer was up to date.